# Dynamic field of my model - ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to edit the data of a specific field. The problem I got is that the field name is a string, for example.

In my view I have the parameter like this:

```
<div class="editable" id="cnso">@Model.cnso</div>
```

I get that field and call my controller via Ajax using [jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable):

```
$('.editable').editable('/Req/UpdateField', {
    tooltip: 'Click to edit...',
    submitdata : {
        nreqid : function() {
            return $("#nreqid").val();
        }
    }
});
```

My controller got the name of the field (cnso) in the string `id`. The problem is to update my model. Some code of my controller.

```
public string UpdateField(string id, string value, int nreqid)
{
    /*
     *        id - id of the field. This value can be used on the
     *             server side to determine what property of the
     *             company should be updated.
     *     value - text that is entered in the input field.
     *    nreqid - this is additional parameter that will
     *             be added to the request. Value of this parameter
     *             is a value of the hidden field with an id "ReqId".
     */
    ModelState.Clear();

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //db.Entry(req).State = EntityState.Modified;
        //db.SaveChanges();
        Req req = db.Req.Find(nreqid);
        req."id" = "2";  // <--- Problem here !!!
    }
}
```

My model object, `Req`, has the field `cnso`, and my `id` string has the "cnso", so how can I select the `cnso` from my string id?

Comment: What does this Req object look like? Is it correct to say your problem is you wish to update a field in req where that field matches your string name?

Comment: @AFinkelstein, the important part is the Object Req has the field cnso. My string id has the string "cnso" that i want to assign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using reflection you could do:

```
Type t = typeof(Req);
PropertyInfo p = t.GetProperty(id);
if(p != null)
    p.SetValue(req, "2", null);
```

Alternatively, if there's not too many properties, you could make a different Update action for all the properties you need. I don't know the circumstances you need this for, but updating individual properties in a table one a time might not be the best design.